# Check Items for checkbox checked in Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-forms, django-views

I am working on a view. I am trying to create a html file that will display a form based on the records model. In the html file I added code that will display all of the members with the group. Next to each of the members, there is a checkbox. In the view.py file, I want to go through each of the members and if the checkbox is checked, I want to create a new transacition object and save it to the database if it is infact checked. I am getting an error and it looks like this...

ERROR:

```
KeyError at /23/addRecord/
'omar'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/23/addRecord/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'omar'
Exception Location: C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in addRecord, line 237
Python Executable:  C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\Desktop\\opentab\\opentab',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36',
 'C:\\Users\\OmarJandali\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 3 Jul 2017 07:02:20 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

C:\Users\OmarJandali\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in addRecord
                            username = cd[member.user.username] ...
▶ Local vars
Request information

GET
No GET data
POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'vIg5KKWVNpoc2ijkwmBB9I28aDt7QOSA'
split   
'2'
omar    
'checked'
hani    
'checked'
submit  
'submit'
```

Here are the files that i have right now.

view.py

```
def addRecord(request, groupId):
    # for the records, the user and group need to be provided to know what group
    # this record is attached to and who created the record.
    user = User.objects.get(username='omar')
    group = Group.objects.get(id=groupId)
    members = Member.objects.filter(group=groupId)
    # the followin process is similar to the form validation for the group view.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = 'process'
        form = AddRecordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            split = cd['split']
            new_record = Record.objects.create(
                split = split,
                status = 1,
                group = group,
                user = user,
            )
            for member in members:
            if member.user.username in request.GET:
                new_transaction = Transaction.objects.create(
                    amount = 0.00,
                    description = 'description',
                    group = group,
                    user = member,
                    record = new_record,
                )
        return redirect('accounts')
    else:
        # the only tyhing that needed to be passed was the group to display the naem
        # and the form that is going to be used and filled out by the user and submitted
        form = AddRecordForm()
        message = 'no processing'
        params = {
            'group':group,
            'members':members,
            'form':form,
            'message':message,
        }
    return render(request, 'tabs/add_record.html', params)
```

html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>add record to {{ group.name }}</h2>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% for member in members %}
      {{ member.user.username }}
      <input name="{{member.user.username}}" value="checked" type="checkbox"><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py file

```
class Record(models.Model):
    split = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1) #user
    count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=RECORD_STATUS_CHOICES, default=1) #server
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #server
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE) #server
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) #server

class Transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9,default=0.00)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

I have tried doing a few different things including altering the form input name and value. I tried a few different ways to alter the cd[] content and how it is checked to see if it was there where the error was occured. Can anyone help me with this tricky situtation.

Comment: the problem is with the get method. there is no username  called omar, check database to get the actual name

Comment: check the value of `print(cd)`

Comment: There is a user with the name omar in my local database. I am using for all of the different testing that i am doing. And when the html file is displayed it shows the username omar with a check box next to it. so that is why i am wondering what this issue is.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yeah i printed it out and it only showed the split which means that is not in the cleaned data. So if that is the issue how can i check and see if the checkbox is selected in the view and create the record if it is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an **error in request.GET**

Instead do,

```
    if member.user.username in request.POST:
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. I was trying to check and see if the check is in .GET but once i used the request.POST, it worked and created the objects. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: Glad to be of some help :D